# MYSQL stored procedures 2 tables, 2 select and 1 update request to the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a function:

```
// Search user who have zero city but not zero country
list($user_id, $country_id) = $site_db->query("
  select user_id, country_id
  from users 
  WHERE city_id < 1 AND country_id > 1
  LIMIT 1");

// If user found, get random city from user country
if ($user_id > 0) 
{
  $random_city_query = $site_db->query("
    select id 
    from cities 
    WHERE country_id = $country_id 
    order by RAND() 
    limit 1");

// Update user city
$update_city = $site_db->query("
  update users 
  set city_id = $random_city_query
  WHERE user_id = $user_id");
}
```

I try to create **MYSQL stored procedure** on the base of this function.

I try already some variants and it wont work :(

```
BEGIN
update users u 
set u.city_id = (select ci.id from cities ci WHERE ci.country_id = u.country_id order by RAND() limit 1)
WHERE user_id = (select u.user_id WHERE u.city_id < 1 AND u.country_id > 1 limit 1)
END
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

So, nobody help me :(
I spend 2 more hours and create procedure by myself :)

```
BEGIN
SELECT @user_id := user_id from users WHERE city_id < 1 AND country_id > 1 LIMIT 1;
IF NOT @user_id IS NULL
THEN 
SELECT @user_country_id := country_id from users WHERE user_id = @user_id;
SELECT @city_id := id from cities WHERE country_id = @user_country_id order by RAND() limit 1;
update users set city_id = @city_id WHERE user_id = @user_id;
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score -1):

This way to create stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure sp_ADD_RESPONSABLE_EXTRANET_CLIENT
(
@ParLngId int output
)
as
Begin
if not exists (Select ParLngId from T_Param where ParStrIndex = 'RES' and ParStrP2 = 'Web')
    Begin
            INSERT INTO T_Param values('RES','¤ExtranetClient', 'ECli', 'Web', 1, 1, Null, Null, 'non', 'ExtranetClient', 'ExtranetClient', 25032, Null, 'informatique.interne@septeo.fr', 'Extranet-Client', Null, 27, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, 1, Null, Null, 0 )
            SET @ParLngId = @@IDENTITY
    End
Else
    Begin
            SET @ParLngId = (Select top 1 ParLngId from T_Param where ParStrNom = 'Extranet Client')
            Return @ParLngId
    End   
End
```

Comment: it not help me because I have **if** in my function, which creates problems for me.